# Defined function raises TypeError when tried to be accessed after module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor, typeerror, module.exports

So I followed a udemy course on JS and during the making of an app he writes the code that is written bellow. When I come to run the code an error is raised saying "TypeError: this.validate is not a function". I tried different ways of exporting User and sometimes it told me that it cannot read User as a constructor which is what I want it to be. I have been on this for the past 4 hours and I am still unable to figure out how it works. The whole file is required by other files. When on these other files I create an instance of the object like below. It works although the .push method of an array cannot be accessed(error message pops up)when I call the pushError function

```js
const User = require('../models/User.js')

let user = new User(req.body);
//I can then run the .validate function
user.validate();
//But in that function another error raises that says that the 
//"push cannot be accessed in undefined" 
//And it leads me to think that during the construction the 
//empty list becomes undefined????
```

```js
let User = function(data) {{
    this.username = data.username;
    this.mail = data.email;
    this.password = data.password;
    this.errors = [];
}
}

User.prototype.validate = function(){
    if(this.username.replace(" ","") == ""){pushError("Username")}
    if(this.password == ""){pushError("Password")}
    if(this.mail.replace(" ","") == ""){pushError("Email")}
}

User.prototype.register = ()=>{
    //Step #1: Validate user Data
    this.validate();
    //Step #2:If validated store data to DB
}

function pushError(str){
    
    this.errors.push(`You must provide a valid ${str}.`);
};

module.exports = User;
```

If you read through all this thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `pushError` function is in no way related to the `User` instance you are creating.

Inside `pushError`, `this` is not the new `User` object you're attempting to create, hence `this.errors` is `undefined`, and you cannot call `push` on `undefined`.

Also, writing `register` as an arrow function instead of a regular function makes it lose the value of `this` (`this` becomes that of the enclosing context, `window` in a browser or `global` in Node.js).

There three steps involved to solve this.

First you should rewrite `pushError` as part of `User`'s prototype chain, like so:

```js
User.prototype.pushError = function(str) {
    this.errors.push(`You must provide a valid ${str}.`);
};
```

Second, you should use `this.pushError` instead of `pushError` in `validate`:

```js
User.prototype.validate = function() {
    if (this.username.replace(" ", "") == "") {
        this.pushError("Username");
    }
    if (this.password == "") {
        this.pushError("Password");
    }
    if (this.mail.replace(" ","") == "") {
        this.pushError("Email");
    }
}
```

Third, write `register` as a regular function:

```js
User.prototype.register = function() {
    //Step #1: Validate user Data
    this.validate();
    //Step #2:If validated store data to DB
}
```

That should do it. Now, a few additional comments and resources. It might help you to:

- Dig into [JavaScript Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects) on MDN, especially the [Object prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) section.
- Write your code as an ES6 class, which is a more "modern" way to do the same thing: [this article](https://www.toptal.com/javascript/es6-class-chaos-keeps-js-developer-up) gives examples of how to write things the "prototype way" or with classes.
- Learn more about the differences between regular and "fat arrow" functions in [this article](https://medium.com/better-programming/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions-f65639aba256).

Comment: I see thank you. But how do I fix the error I get when I try to call the "this.validate()" function in the User.prototype.register (which says that this.validate isn't a function)? Again thank you for the help you have provided already I appreciate that!

Comment: I edited my answer, the third point should solve your problem. Cheers!

Comment: Glad my answer helped! Please consider accepting it :).